# UIImageView in UIScrolView. How to scale UIImageView proportionally in iphone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am new to objective C.
I use Auto Layout in the Main storyboard.

http://i61.tinypic.com/kd25gx.jpg
[image]

http://i59.tinypic.com/2guw38k.jpg
[image]

There are upper parts of print screen (I cut, down parts) from xcode Simulator for iphone 5, iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus
How you see image in iphone 5 is from side to side. The same how in the Main Storyboard

In iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus there are empty space on the both sides. I use 640x600 images for ihone 5 and 960x900 images for iphone 6 and 6 plus
I think code is require to scale UIImageView proportionally from side to side for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your constraints, You are added wrong constraints. First cleat all constraint you are given to image view & then add constraint to image as leading, trailing top & height you want. It will solve your problem Or if needed make image view's mode as scaleToFill.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem. But it sounds like you want to remove the spaces from the image to the sides, right?

If you are not sure about the `UIImageView`'s proportions, then give it a backgroundColor to indicate that for you - just a tip.

If your `UIImageView`'s constraints places the `UIImageView` correctly with the full width from side to side then take a look at the `contentMode` on your `UIImageView`.

[image: contentMode]

This is an overview for `contentMode`s.
Right now it seems like the image in your `UIImageView` have the "Aspect Fit" `contentMode`. This sets your image to fit the `UIImageView` with the biggest side (width/height) first and scales the other side proportionally after the biggest side. This means if the `UIImageView` doesn't have the exact same proportions as the image, it will leave blank spaces.

Instead you should look at "Scale to fit" or "Aspect to fit" if you don't want these spaces. 
The image above describes pretty well what the difference between these is.

You can set the `contentMode` for a `UIImageView` like this:

```
// Aspect to fill
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

// Scale to fill
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Hope it helps :)